# How do I embed the values of the arguments in JavaScript's Function.prototype.toString?

Tags: javascript, closures

I need to get a string representation of a function, with its corresponding values of arguments.

Imagine the following statement:

```js
const r1 = (x) => abc(x, 2);
```

Executing `r1.toString()` would give a string `"x => abc(x, 2)"`.

Now, imagine I modify the previous piece of code like this:

```js
const create = y => (x => abc(x, y));
const r2 = create(2);
```

Although `r1` and `r2` are equivalent in terms of the execution (they will both call `abc`, passing `2` as the second argument), the string representation will be different. In fact, `r2.toString()` will now give `"x => abc(x, y)"`.

How do I modify either the `create` function ro the `r2.toString()` to have the same output as `r1.toString()`?

Comment: This would be non-trivial. Also a weird use-case. Are you trying to serialise partially applied functions and such?

Comment: @VLAZ: a bit of context may help. The thing is being used when serializing the state of a grid in agGrid. The application captures not only the data, but also the way the data is presented, which includes `cellRenderer`—a function which defines how the cells in a given column are formatted. As I refactored this part of the code, I inadvertently broke this feature, as the arguments are not serialized. As a result, I'm trying to figure out the best way to restore the feature, while keeping the refactoring.

Comment: Uh...well, the *most reliable* way I can think of is 1. Parse the function into an AST 2. drop the outer function (since it's being applied) 3. Replace the outer parameter with the argument that was passed in in the AST. (so, changing from variable to a literal) 4. Collapse the AST back into code. That will avoid dropping random other stuff where a similar name would be used. It's a "do it yourself inlining" in a way. But also not the easiest and fastest to do. You could try with regex replacements into the `toString()` source but it might detect a variable where there isn't.

Comment: Overall, I'm not sure there is an *easy* and/or "cheap" way to do that. Well, although I'm thinking of the more general case. If all you have is two-level curried functions, might be easier to solve just for those.

Comment: The context you mentioned to VLAZ is called _State Management_. You should not be be capturing the function parameters, you should capturing and recording the effect they have - the state of the system. Then restore the state. Your `cellRenderer()` method can be edited to do this for you.